# Get Campaign Location from Adwords

Tags: java, location, google-ads-api

Im having a little problem regarding campaign location, i cant pull the location using the adwords api.

Im using java by the way, here is my code:

```
SelectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder();
Selector selector = builder
    .fields(
        CampaignCriterionField.CampaignId,
        CampaignCriterionField.Id,
        CampaignCriterionField.CriteriaType,
        CampaignCriterionField.PlatformName,
        CampaignCriterionField.LanguageName,
        CampaignCriterionField.LocationName,
        CampaignCriterionField.KeywordText)
    .in(CampaignCriterionField.CriteriaType, "KEYWORD", "LANGUAGE", "LOCATION", "PLATFORM")
    .offset(0)
    .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    .build();

CampaignCriterionPage page = null;
do {
  page = campaignCriterionService.get(selector);

  if (page.getEntries() != null) {
    // Display campaigns.
    for (CampaignCriterion campaignCriterion : page.getEntries()) {
        Location loc = (Location)campaignCriterion.getCriterion();
      System.out.println(loc.getLocationName());
    }
```

Im having an error regarding casting. here it is.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Language cannot be cast to com.google.api.ads.adwords.axis.v201506.cm.Location

Hope you can help me regarding this, Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the return type of `campaignCriteria.getCriterion()`? I'm guessing it's `Language`, but your code assumes it's `Location`?

Comment: i added additional info about my Code. i don't know how it is done. can you provide me an example on how to get the location? please thanks.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know the adwords API and am struggling to match your code to [the javadoc I can find online](http://googleads.github.io/googleads-java-lib/2.4.0/index.html). Are you using version 2.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using LocationCriterionService
Code:

```
Location loc = (Location)campaignCriterion.getCriterion();
        System.out.println(loc.getLocationName());
```

And by Selecting LOCATION to the selector.